# Magento Downloadable Products Link Expired

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this situation.
[image]

I set max downloads to unlimited, and I got status Expired for this user.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your response as the answer and mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The problem was that user cancelled the order in payment process.